# May a Jew stare at an "image" of an ancient idol?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, pictures

In SA, YD, siman 142:15,

> אסור לשמוע כלי שיר של אלילים או להסתכל בנוי אלילים כיון שנהנה בראייה

My question is, does the image of an idol (ancient Sumerian, Egyptian, Canaanite) have the same status as the idol itself?

Comment: Are you only asking according to the opinion of the Shulhan Arukh (which may be impossible to determine), or are you asking about he law according to all Jewish source?

Comment: According to all sources!

Comment: Does this apply when the idol is effectively disowned by the world? No one worships Sumerian gods anymore, afaik, and there are halachos about the nullification of an Avodah Zarah...